# OrmLite, calendar and timestamp

Tags: android, calendar, timestamp, ormlite

I am having a problem with some OrmLite mapping with java fields in android.

1) I have Calendar type in java class, and in SQLlite the same field defined as TimeStamp, when I run a method `findAll()` I get folowing exception:

```
ORMLite can't store unknown class class java.util.Calendar for field
     'Start'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

if I use `setDataType(DataType.SERIALIZABLE);` I'm getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not read serialized object from byte array: [50, 48,
```

Also I have tried with the `DataType.TIME_STAMP` but then I'm getting this error:

```
Field class java.util.Calendar for field FieldType:name=Start,class=PeriodTest is
     not valid for type com.j256.ormlite.field.types.TimeStampType@416f9ea0,
     maybe should be class java.sql.Timestamp
```

2) I have the same problem with the TimeStamp (DataType.TIME_STAMP) java class. For example:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14662): java.lang.Error: java.sql.SQLException:
     Could not assign object 'Mon Jul 01 09:46:12 CEST 2013' to field
     FieldType:name=timestamp
```

Does anybody know the solution for these two cases?

Thanx in advance, Oggie

**Solution:**

-Data needs to be serialized and inserted like that into db in order to be read afterwords.
I dont know how I didnt realize this earlier but....

Comment: Here is a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872880/orm-lite-throws-error-when-creating-tables-containing-multi-level-foreign-key

Comment: I dont have issue with the foreign key, nor with the custom class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORMLite can't store unknown class class java.util.Calendar for field
  'Start'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

This is trying to tell you that [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) doesn't natively know about the `Calendar` type.  It doesn't know how to represent it in SQL.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not read serialized object from byte array: [50, 48,
```

Yeah.  If you already have data stored in the database then storing a serializable field is not an option.

```
Field class java.util.Calendar for field FieldType:name=Start,class=PeriodTest is
   not valid for type com.j256.ormlite.field.types.TimeStampType@416f9ea0,
   maybe should be class java.sql.Timestamp
```

This is saying that ORMLite can't map from a `Calendar` to a `Timestamp`.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14662): java.lang.Error: java.sql.SQLException:
   Could not assign object 'Mon Jul 01 09:46:12 CEST 2013' to field
   FieldType:name=timestamp
```

This sounds like there is a string in the database but a `Timestamp` field.  Without the full exception however it's hard to know what's going on.

> Data needs to be serialized and inserted like that into db in order to be read afterwords.

This is correct and it sounds like you have your solution but for posterity, there are a couple other things you can do.

If you are just using `Calendar` to store a date/time then switching to using some other type (like `Date`, or `DateTime`) would be recommended.  You could also write a custom persister.  See: [Map PostgreSql money data type to ORMLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965829/map-postgresql-money-data-type-to-ormlite/9976827#9976827).